# Using commas with "not for... but for"

Tags: punctuation

I wanted to ask about using commas with "not for... but for"
My sentence is similar to the one below:

> Why don't we buy presents, not for our family, but for those in need?

Note that for specific reasons I can not change the way the statement is written.

Are the commas placed correctly? I feel like I overdid it.
Also another question is it possible to omit the but.
Like so:

> Why don't we buy presents, not for our family, for those in need?

Comment: Looks OK to me except that it needs a question mark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why don't we buy presents, not for our family, but for those in need?

That seems correct with regard to the comma placement.

> Why don't we buy presents, not for our family, for those in need?

This is not good. You need to include the "but," otherwise it is a run-on sentence.

Also, this is a very conversational sounding sentence. If you were speaking conversationally, you might say those words, but it would come out more like "Why don't we buy presents? Not for our family; for those in need." Even though the second sentence here is not grammatically complete, it comes as a natural response in a conversation, i.e.

> Person A: "Why don't we buy presents?
>
> Person B: "For our family?"
>
> Person A: "Not for our family; for those in need.

But if you're talking strictly grammar, you need the "but" in there to make the sentence correct.